# Nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, test

tengo un problema que me impide avanzar y ya no se como solucionarlo. Tengo una clase llamada Validator donde guardo funciones de validaciones y necesito hacer test unitarios para cada una y validar su funcionalidad, pero hay algunas de ellas que utilizan la instancia Environment de Spring en el que accede al archivo de properties. Si hago test unitarios "normal" siempre que llama a la función donde se implementa esta característica me devuelve Environment es null. He probado en utilizar **@Autowired** en vez de instanciar con **new** en la clase de test, el uso de **@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)** y como las clases de los test y las clases de las funciones estan en paquetes distintos tambien he usado el **@ComponentScan** y me da error... En que me estoy equivocando o que estoy haciendo mal ?

El código de la clase Validator lo tengo de esta forma:

```
@Component
public class Validator {
        
    @Autowired
    public Environment env;
    
    public CodRespuestaWS validarTipoOperacion(TipoOperacion tipoOperacion, String operacion) {
        
        String respuesta = env.getProperty(tipoOperacion.toString() + "." + operacion);
        if (OK.equalsIgnoreCase(respuesta)) {
            return new CodRespuestaWS();
        }
        return new CodRespuestaWS(CodRespuestaWS.ER100, tipoOperacion.toString()+" no permitida:" + operacion);
    }

}
```

Y en el test lo hago de esta forma:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "es.funciones.validators")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

public class ValidarPeticionAltaTest {

    PeticionAlta peticionAlta = new PeticionAlta();
    CodRespuestaWS respuesta;
    @Autowired Validator validador;
    
    AltaValidator altaValidador = new AltaValidator();
    DatosUsuario datosUsuario = new DatosUsuario();
    
    
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        respuesta = validador.validarTipoOperacion(TipoOperacion.tipoOperacionAlta, "alta");
        System.out.println(respuesta.getCodRespuesta());
    }
}
```

El problema que comentaba antes del NULL, es que al ejecutar el test no llegaba ni al print que tengo puesto, si no que se quedaba en la linea

> String respuesta = env.getProperty(tipoOperacion.toString() + "." +
> operacion);

Y marcaba el error de que env era NULL y ahora me devuelve otro distinto

Y el error que me devuelve ahora es:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'funcionestest.unittest.ValidarPeticionAltaTest': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'validador'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type 'es.funciones.validators.Validator' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Supongo que ya se entiende, pero lo detallo más por si acaso, las funciones están en

***src/main/java/es.funciones.validators/Validators.java***

Y los test

***src/main/test/funcionestest.unittest/ValidarPeticionAltaTest.java***

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de Spring Boot utilizas?

Comment: Tengo la 5.1.2.RELEASE

Comment: La version de spring boot que especificas no existe, esa version podría se la de Spring Core,  para ir descartando casos agrega la siguiente annotation `@SpringBootTest` junto con `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` y prueba nuevamente el test.

Comment: Hola, disculpa como podria ver realmente la versión correctamente ? Aun usando la connotación SpringBootTest me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Para ver la version, en la sección parent se encuentra el artifact  `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>` y la la version `<version>2.6.4</version>` si utilizas maven.

Comment: Esta es la versión que me indica: 2.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Entonces con tener las anotaciones @SpringBootTest junto con @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) deberia de funcionar, prueba quitar el @ComponentScan(basePackages = "es.funciones.validators") y verificar el import de las anotaciones sean de los paquetes correctos.

Comment: Si hago como tu me dices me indica este error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a **@SpringBootConfiguration**, you need to use **@ContextConfiguration** or **@SpringBootTest(classes=...)** with your test

Comment: He conseguido solucionarlo añadiendo **@SpringBootTest(classes = Validator.class)**

Comment: Lo que sucede es que no estas cargando el contexto de Spring, como utilizas SpringBoot cambia la clase Validator por la clase principal de SpringBoot con la que inicias el contexto que tiene el método main, con eso te debería de poder inyectar cualquier bean.

Comment: Eso entiendo que pasa cuando añades **@SpringBooTest** a secas o añades otra clase que no es la que estas enfocando el contexto, no ?

Comment: En tu caso es raro porque SpringBootTest debería iniciar el contexto completo y RunWith(SpringRunner.class) es quien te permite inyectar en el test, al menos por lo que muestras no se puede idénticar porque no se inicia el contexto en automático, en las nuevas versiones creo que desde la 2.6.0 actualizaron a Junit5 y solo necesitas  la anotación @SpringBooTest.

Comment: Quizás tenga que ver que use JUnit 4

Comment: Bueno eso es porque Junit4 es el que tiene por defecto la version de Spring Boot que utiliza en la dependencia `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>` si la agregaste manual puede ser el causante del problema.

Comment: Manualmente te refieres a que haya añadido la dependencia de junit4 en el pom, no ?